# Finding the 2nd lowest number without using lists, functions, or dictionary

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a program where the user inputs a certain number of students, their names, and their test scores, and the program should print the 2nd lowest score and the student name. I am new to python and I have not learned collections like lists and dictionary, so please keep it simple with if, else, and while loops. Below is the code I have so far that prints the second highest number instead of the second lowest.

```
n= int(input("Enter number of students:"))
low_name= ','
low_name_2= ','
low_score= 0
low_score_2= 0
for i in range(n):
    name= input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "name:\n")
    score= int(input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "score:\n"))
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
            print("Please enter score in range of 0-100")
            score= int(input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "score:\n"))

    if score > low_score:
           low_name_2 = low_name
           low_score_2 = low_score
           low_name = name
           low_score = score


    elif score > low_score_2:
            low_score_2 = score
            low_name_2 = name
print("2nd lowest student is ", low_name_2 , " with score ", str(low_score_2))
```

Comment: What prevents you from modifying the program to find the second _lowest_ number?

Comment: Task doesn't say anything about heaps, so use heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was close. Just simply change the `low_score` and `low_score_2` to 101 in your declaration of them and then change the `>` signs to a `<` sign in the `if` statements.

Final code:

```
n= int(input("Enter number of students:"))
low_name= ','
low_name_2= ','
low_score=101
low_score_2=101
for i in range(n):
    name= input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "name:\n")
    score= int(input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "score:\n"))
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        print("Please enter score in range of 0-100")
        score= int(input("Please enter student" + str(i+1) + "score:\n"))

    if score < low_score:
       low_name_2 = low_name
       low_score_2 = low_score
       low_name = name
       low_score = score
    elif score < low_score_2:
       low_score_2 = score
       low_name_2 = name
print("2nd lowest student is ", low_name_2 , " with score ", str(low_score_2))
```